# ¿Como hacer esta consulta en sql server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo un problema a la hora de intentar hacer una consulta, les explico lo que tengo:

tengo unos horarios de X aparato, para calcular las horas de funcionamiento contra las horas que tiene fallas, lo que necesito es una consulta para totalizar las horas de funcionamiento al mes. Me explico, tengo una tabla que tengo las horas de funcionamiento de Lunes-Viernes, los sabados, y los domingos. Por ejemplo: X aparato funciona de Lunes a Viernes de 7:00 AM a 8:00PM, los sabados de 8:00AM a 8:00PM y los domingos de 8:AM a 12:00PM. Entonces la idea es sacar cuantas horas deberian trabajar al mes, pero estoy trabado en la consulta, quisiera que se pudiera recorrer todo el mes, es decir ir sumando las horas que se trabajan al mes.

Las tablas HORARIOS es esta:

```
CREATE TABLE [Horarios](
    [COD_ATM] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LV_INI] [datetime] NULL,
    [LV_FIN] [datetime] NULL,
    [SA_INI] [datetime] NULL,
    [SA_FIN] [datetime] NULL,
    [DO_INI] [datetime] NULL,
    [DO_FIN] [datetime] NULL)
```

LV_INI = Lunes A Viernes Inicia a trabajar
LV_FIN= Lunes A Viernes Deja de trabajar (asi los demas tambien)
Algunos datos:

```
COD_ATM LV_INI               LV_FIN                 SA_INI             
                             SA_FIN                 DO_INI         DO_FIN
1   2014-06-09 07:00:00.000 2014-06-09 20:00:00.000 2014-06-09 07:00:00.000 2014-06-09 20:00:00.000 2014-06-09 07:00:00.000 2014-06-09 20:00:00.000
2   2014-06-09 08:00:00.000 2014-06-09 16:00:00.000 2014-06-09 08:00:00.000 2014-06-09 12:00:00.000 2014-06-09 00:00:00.000 2014-06-09 00:00:00.000
3   2014-06-09 00:00:00.000 2014-06-09 23:59:00.000 2014-06-09 00:00:00.000 2014-06-09 23:59:00.000 2014-06-09 00:00:00.000 2014-06-09 23:59:00.000
4   2014-06-09 07:00:00.000 2014-06-09 20:00:00.000 2014-06-09 07:00:00.000 2014-06-09 20:00:00.000 2014-06-09 07:00:00.000 2014-06-09 20:00:00.000
5   2014-06-09 08:00:00.000 2014-06-09 20:00:00.000 2014-06-09 08:00:00.000 2014-06-09 20:00:00.000 2014-06-09 08:00:00.000 2014-06-09 20:00:00.000
6   2014-06-09 07:00:00.000 2014-06-09 21:00:00.000 2014-06-09 07:00:00.000 2014-06-09 21:00:00.000 2014-06-09 07:00:00.000 2014-06-09 21:00:00.000
```

Y la consulta que tengo es esta:

```
    /****** Promedio de horas ******/
    SELECT COD_ATM,
    sum(convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, LV_INI, LV_FIN))*5) as LunesAViernes,
    sum(convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, SA_INI, SA_FIN))) as Sabado,
    sum(convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, DO_INI, DO_FIN))) as Domingo,
    sum((convert(int, (DATEDIFF(HOUR, LV_INI, LV_FIN))*5) + convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, SA_INI, SA_FIN)) + convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, DO_INI, DO_FIN)))) AS TOTAL,
    sum((convert(int, (DATEDIFF(HOUR, LV_INI, LV_FIN))*5) + convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, SA_INI, SA_FIN)) + convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, DO_INI, DO_FIN)))*4) AS TOTAL
FROM [ATMs].[dbo].[AT1203]
group by COD_ATM, LV_INI, LV_FIN
```

Entonces en esta consulta los calculo asumiendo que el mes tiene 4 semanas. Lo que quisiera hacer es sumar de acuerdo al mes que estoy.

Y lo que obtengo es esto: Se acerca a los datos deseados pero no es lo que deseo

```
COD_ATM LunesAViernes   Sabado  Domingo TOTAL   TOTAL
1         65               13       13    91    364
2         40               4        0     44    176
3        115              23        23    161   644
4         65              13        13     91   364
5         60              12        12     84   336
6         70              14        14     98   392
```

Espero haberme dado a entender, cualquier duda estare pendiente.
Aclaro que los campo fecha no son necesarios, lo que ocupo de esos campos es la la hora de inicio y la hora de finalizacion respectivamente.

Un ejemplo esperado seria el siguiente para el ATM 1, Septiembre tiene 5 sabados, 4 domingos, y 21 dias de la semana. Entoces el ATM1 trabaja de de Lunes A Vierdes de 7AM a 8PM, lo que quiere decir que trabaja 13 horas diarias, si lo multiplicamos por 21 obtenemos las horas que trabaja a la semana(Lunes a Viernes) que seria 273 horas a la semana y son 4 domingos (4 domingos * 13) = 52 
igual el sabado = 52

```
Entoces el total trabajado seria:
273 los dias de la semana
52 los sabados
52 los domingos 
**377 Total**. Ese seria el resultado esperado, **y en la consulta que tengo solo me salen 364**
```

Comment: aclara cual es la tabla que quieres obtener..

Comment: Quisiera obtener los datos que tengo al final, pero de forma que si el mes tiene 5 sabados me sume las horas que se trabajo por los 5 sabados. Si tiene 4 domingos sume las horas que se trabajo el domingo, y asi sucesivamente. mi consulta funciona pero no es exacta, ya que yo solo asumo que el mes tiene 4 semanas y no cumplo por asi decirlo con todos los dias del mes. No se si se entiende

Comment: perfecto, eso no me habia quedado claro. tienes un registro por dia? o aparte de las horas como guardan las fechas?

Comment: No tengo registro por día, solo tengo esa fecha de inicio y fin, y en base a esos horarios calcular las horas que se espera que trabajen los ATM al mes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que partirás de un rango de fechas a listar, la siguiente es la forma "fácil" de resolver tu problema, que básicamente pasa por calcular que día de semana es cada fecha que hay entre los rangos solicitados. Veamos como sería:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

DECLARE @FechaDesde     DATETIME
DECLARE @FechaHasta     DATETIME

SELECT  @FechaDesde     = '20170113'
SELECT  @FechaHasta     = '20170521'
```

Primero que nada `SET DATEFIRST 1` para asegurarnos que todos los calculos se basen en que nuestro primer día de semana sea un lunes. Luego establecemos las fechas a listar.

```
-- Horas semanales de cada ATM
DECLARE @HorasATMSemana TABLE (
    COD_ATM     INT, 
    DiaSemana   INT,
    Horas       INT
)

INSERT INTO @HorasATMSemana (COD_ATM, Diasemana, Horas)
VALUES  (1, 1, 13), (1, 2, 13), (1, 3, 13), (1, 4, 13), (1, 5, 13), (1, 6, 12), (1, 7, 16),
    (2, 1,  8), (2, 2,  8), (2, 3,  8), (2, 4,  8), (2, 5,  8), (2, 6,  8), (2, 7,  8)
```

Lo siguiente es una reformulación de tu tabla `Horarios`, en vez de tener fechas de inicio y fin, tengo el ATM, el día de semana y las horas que le corresponden para ese día, según tu ejemplo 13 de lunes a viernes, 12 los sábados y 16 los domingos (agregue otro ATM con otro régimen a modo de prueba). Todo esto simplemente para hacerlo un poco más sencillo y más fácil de entender, pero tranquilamente podrías usar tu tabla `Horarios` y generar una estructura similar a esta. Luego, viene lo importante que es generar nuestro conjunto de Fechas desde `@FechaDesde` hasta `@FechaHasta` y a cada fecha le calculamos que día de semana es.

```
-- Generamos las fechas (1000 dias)
DECLARE @Fechas TABLE (
    Nro         INT,
    DiaSemana   INT,
    Fecha   DATETIME    
)

INSERT INTO @Fechas(Nro)
SELECT  (T1.NRO-1)*100 + (T2.NRO-1)*10 + T3.NRO
    FROM ( SELECT 1 AS 'NRO' UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) T1 
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS 'NRO' UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) T2
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS 'NRO' UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) T3
    ORDER BY T1.NRO,T2.NRO,T3.NRO

UPDATE  @Fechas
    SET DiaSemana = DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, Nro-1, @FechaDesde)),
    Fecha =  DATEADD(DAY, Nro-1, @FechaDesde)
```

Hay varios métodos para generar secuencias en SQL, en este ejemplo usamos un producto cartesiano de 3 consultas de 10 valores los que nos dará un total de 1000 registros, ese será nuestro rango máximo de días, si necesitamos más hay que modificar esta consulta.

Por último hacemos la consulta final:

```
SELECT  D.COD_ATM,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.DiaSemana BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN D.Horas ELSE 0 END) AS 'LaV',
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.DiaSemana = 6             THEN D.Horas ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sab',
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.DiaSemana = 7             THEN D.Horas ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dom',
    SUM(D.Horas)                                                       AS 'Tot'
    FROM @Fechas F
    INNER JOIN @HorasATMSemana D
        ON D.DiaSemana = F.DiaSemana 
    WHERE F.Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde AND @FechaHasta
    GROUP BY D.COD_ATM
```

Que nos retornaría algo así

```
COD_ATM LaV      Sab     Dom     Tot
------- -------- ------- ------- --------
1,00    1.183,00 228,00  304,00  1.715,00
2,00    728,00   152,00  152,00  1.032,00
```

Antes te decía que esta era la forma "fácil", por que si mal no recuerdo hay una formula más directa para calcular cuantos días laborables, sábados y domingos hay en un intervalo, sabiendo estos números  simplemente es cuestión de multiplicar las horas y sumarlas. Si encuentro esta otra solución lo agrego a la respuesta.

**Editado:**
Como te decía la otra forma es calculando cuantos días de semana hay en un rango de fechas ([Esta pregunta ayudó mucho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563069/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-tuesdays-between-two-dates-in-tsql)), es más simple y no requiere una tabla intermedia.

```
SELECT  D.COD_ATM,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.DiaSemana BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN D.Horas * F.Cant ELSE 0 END) AS 'LaV',
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.DiaSemana = 6             THEN D.Horas * F.Cant ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sab',
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.DiaSemana = 7             THEN D.Horas * F.Cant ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dom',
    SUM(D.Horas*F.Cant)                                                         AS 'Tot'
    FROM @HorasATMSemana D
    INNER JOIN  (
        SELECT  1 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -7, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -6, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  2 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -6, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -5, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  3 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -5, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  4 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -3, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  5 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -3, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  6 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant UNION
        SELECT  7 AS Diasemana, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY,  0, @FechaDesde)/7 AS Cant
    ) F
    ON F.Diasemana = D.Diasemana
    GROUP BY D.COD_ATM
```

Finalmente, para tu ejemplo que necesitas los días Lunes a viernes, sábados y domingos, podrías hacer un join directamente con esta tabla y obtener cuantos días hay de cada uno en el mes

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

DECLARE @FechaDesde     DATETIME
DECLARE @FechaHasta     DATETIME

SELECT  @FechaDesde     = '20170901'
SELECT  @FechaHasta     = '20170930'

SELECT  DATEDIFF(DAY, -7, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -6, @FechaDesde)/7 +
    DATEDIFF(DAY, -6, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -5, @FechaDesde)/7 +
    DATEDIFF(DAY, -5, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, @FechaDesde)/7 +
    DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -3, @FechaDesde)/7 +
    DATEDIFF(DAY, -3, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, @FechaDesde)/7 AS 'LaV',
    DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, @FechaDesde)/7 AS 'Sab',
    DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY,  0, @FechaDesde)/7 AS 'Dom'

LaV     Sab     Dom
------- ------- -------
21,00   5,00    4,00
```

Finalmente podría quedarte algo así:

```
SELECT  COD_ATM,
    sum(convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, LV_INI, LV_FIN)) * B.LaV) as LunesAViernes,
    sum(convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, SA_INI, SA_FIN)) * B.Sab) as Sabado,
    sum(convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, DO_INI, DO_FIN)) * B.Dom) as Domingo
    FROM [ATMs].[dbo].[AT1203] A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, -7, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -6, @FechaDesde)/7 +
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -6, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -5, @FechaDesde)/7 +
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -5, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, @FechaDesde)/7 +
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -3, @FechaDesde)/7 +
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -3, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, @FechaDesde)/7 AS 'LaV',
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, @FechaDesde)/7 AS 'Sab',
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, @FechaHasta)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY,  0, @FechaDesde)/7 AS 'Dom'
        ) B
    GROUP BY COD_ATM, LV_INI, LV_FIN
```

Comment: Voy a tratar de implementar eso, ya que no tengo posibilidad de modificar tablas. Te aviso cualquier cosa. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: No dispongo de un rango inicial, ya que solo se pide por mes.

Comment: Un rango de fechas vas a tener siempre, si solo se pide por mes, entonces tu "fecha desde" va a ser el primer día del mes y tu "fecha hasta" el último. Acabo de editar la respuesta y agregué una segunda forma de calcular esto.

Comment: No he podido aplicarlo porque no se me permite tablas intermedias. :(

Comment: Verifica lo último que agregué, sin tablas intermedias y directamente aplicada a tu consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente quedo asi:

```
SELECT  COD_ATM,
    sum(convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, LV_INI, LV_FIN)) * B.LaV) as LunesAViernes,
    sum(convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, SA_INI, SA_FIN)) * B.Sab) as Sabado,
    sum(convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, DO_INI, DO_FIN)) * B.Dom) as Domingo,
    sum((convert(int, datediff(hour, LV_INI, LV_FIN)) * B.Lav) + (convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, SA_INI, SA_FIN)) * B.Sab) + (convert(int, DATEDIFF(HOUR, DO_INI, DO_FIN)) * B.Dom)) as Total_Horas_Trabajadas
    FROM [ATMs].[dbo].[AT1203] A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, -7, EOMONTH (GETDATE()))/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -6, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)))/7 +
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -6, EOMONTH (GETDATE()))/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -5, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)))/7 +
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -5, EOMONTH (GETDATE()))/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)))/7 +
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -4, EOMONTH (GETDATE()))/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -3, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)))/7 +
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -3, EOMONTH (GETDATE()))/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)))/7 AS 'LaV',
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, EOMONTH (GETDATE()))/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)))/7 AS 'Sab',
            DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, EOMONTH (GETDATE()))/7-DATEDIFF(DAY,  0, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)))/7 AS 'Dom'
        ) B
    GROUP BY COD_ATM, LV_INI, LV_FIN
```

Quedando asi:

```
1   273    65      52   390
2   168    20      0    188
3   483    115     92   690
4   273    65      52   390
5   252    60      48   360
6   294    70      56   420
7   252    60      48   360
```